# How to fix this loop thru for Items on page to push to Shopping Cart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, foreach

I have this piece of code that When function is called it adds that one product found into the shopping cart.

How can I update this to loop thru for each itme listed on the page, Each Item has a Unique ID **(uProdID)**?

```
                //Check if the product already exist in Cart if exist update quantity
                for (var a in productCart) {
                    if (productName == productCart[a].productName && giftPrice == productCart[a].productPrice){
                        prdQty = productCart[a].productQty++;
                        updateCart();
                        addToCart();
                        //Update Cart Summary Top Header
                        updateCartSummary();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
```

Here is the unique ID & how it is associated.

var prodId = $(this).attr('id');

var onlyProdId = prodId.substring(4);

I know we should be using a each function to loop thru each item on page but this is what we add and it seem incorrect, any help will be great

the Entire Add to Cart function, it is NOT adding any item, because it only looking for o

```
// Add to Cart
// This Begins process of building User Customized Card Order
// Step 1. In Adding Product (Detail) QTY in Cookie and Session
// QTY is all that can be take from here.
function addToCart(){
       $('.product_item_details').each(function(){
        // Gather the uniquq ID for each Product Item
        // This will only look at all the items add from 
        //Customization

        var uProdID = $('#uProductID').val();
        alert('product_item_'+uProdID);
        var productName = $('#productName').val();
        var productPrice = $('#productPrice').val();
        var productImage = $('#productImage').val();
        var productDesc = $('#productDesc').val();
        var productShortDesc = $('#productShortDesc').val();
        var productTextblock = $('#productTextblock').val();
        var productID = $('#productID').val();
        var numProdID = $('#numProdID').val();




            //This is the Array for Adding Multiple Products
            //This will take the eNumerated Customized Product
            //Create from the hidden Fields
            //this has been conditioned for Sub-item Ordereing
            //MG see Hidden Fields in function customize()
            //MG 01-2014                
            productsArr['product_item_'+uProdID] = {
                        productName: productName,
                        productPrice: productPrice,
                        productImage: productImage,
                        productDesc: productDesc,
                        productShortDesc: productShortDesc,                             
                        productTextblock: productTextblock,                                     
                        uProductID: uProdID,
                        productID: productID,
                     };                  


            // Product Specs
                var prodId = $(this).attr('id');

                //Loop through each Individual Item
                //Here you can monitor the IDs for each
                //prod_item_id_ etc.
                //MG 01-2014
                //var onlyProdId = prodId.substring(4);
                var onlyProdId = uProdID;                   

                var productName = productsArr[prodId].productName;
                var productImage = productsArr[prodId].productImage;
                var productDesc = productsArr[prodId].productDesc;  
                var productShortDesc = productsArr[prodId].productShortDesc;    
                var productTextblock = productsArr[prodId].productTextblock;
                var tempPPrice = productsArr[prodId].productPrice;
                var productID = productsArr[prodId].productID;
                var numProdID = productsArr[prodId].numProdID;  

                var giftPrice = parseFloat($('#gift_'+onlyProdId).val());
                var toname =    $('#toname_'+onlyProdId).val(); 
                var Fromname =  $('#Fromname_'+onlyProdId).val();   
                var selectPersonalMessage =  $('#selectPersonalMessage_'+onlyProdId).val();
                var selectCarrierMessage =  $('#selectCarrierMessage_'+onlyProdId).val();                   

                if(!giftPrice || (giftPrice == '')){
                    return false;
                }

                var productTax = $('#tax_'+onlyProdId).val();
                var prdQty = 1;
                //Check if the product already exist in Cart if exist update quantity
                for (var a in productCart) {
                    if (productName == productCart[a].productName && giftPrice == productCart[a].productPrice){
                        prdQty = productCart[a].productQty++;
                        updateCart();
                        //Update Cart Summary Top Header
                        updateCartSummary();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                //alert(prdQty);

                // Product to cart Array
                productCart.push({
                        productName: productName,
                        productImage: productImage,
                        productDesc: productDesc,
                        productShortDesc: productShortDesc,
                        productTextblock: productTextblock,
                        productPrice: giftPrice,                            
                        productTax: productTax,
                        productToName: toname,
                        productFromName: Fromname,
                        productMessage: selectPersonalMessage,
                        productCarrierMessgae: selectCarrierMessage,                            
                        productQty: 1,
                        uProductID: onlyProdId,
                        productID:productID
                     });


                //alert(productCart);    
                //update cart item id
                cart_item_ids++;
                //Update cart
                updateCart();
                //Update Cart Summary Top Header
                updateCartSummary();
                //order is not submitted yet
                isOrderSubmitted = false;

                return false;
              }); //End Loop thru each Product Item on Customize Page   

             return false;
        }
```

Here is the Out put when three items are select in the customization dropdown, it enumerate with a unique ID to each

```
                          <!-- /Products Holder -->                                
                        <div id="product_item_9_1" class="thumbnails product_item_details"><!-- left infos--><div id="product_item_9_1" class="span4"><!-- add to cart form--><div id="tab-1"><h3 class="ProdNum">Card (1 of 3)</h3></div><!-- hidden datas --> <div class="product_attributes"><div class="content_prices clearfix"><!-- prices --><div class="row_1"><p class="our_price_display" id="gift_value"><label class="control-label" for="gift_9_1">Gift Value: ($20-$500)</label></p><!-- quantity update/wanted --><p id="quantity_wanted_p"><input type="text" name="giftprice" id="gift_9_1" class="input-medium" size="2" maxlength="3" value="20"></p></div><div class="row_1 fee"><p class="our_price_display" id="gift_value"><label class="control-label" for="tax_9_1">Card Fee: <a href="">?</a></label></p><!-- quantity update/wanted --><p id="quantity_wanted_p"><span><label for="fee">$</label><input id="tax_9_1" type="text" class="input-mini fee" readonly="" value="2.95"></span></p></div><div class="row_1"><div id="tab-1"><h3>Card <a href="">?</a></h3> </div><p class="our_price_display" id="gift_value"><label>To Name </label></p><!--quantity update/wanted --><p id="quantity_wanted_p"><span><label for="Toname"></label><input type="text" name="toname" id="toname_9_1" class="inputbox text" value="" size="25" maxlength="26" placeholder="Name"></span></p></div><div class="row_1"><!-- quantity update/wanted --><p id="quantity_wanted_p"><select id="selectPersonalMessage_9_1" class="selectProductSort" name="selectPersonalMessage" style="width:170px;"><option value="">Add a  Message</option><option value="I appreciate you">I appreciate you</option><option value="Happy Birthday">Happy Birthday</option></select></p></div> </div><!-- carrier message and information --><span class="Carrier"><div id="tab-2"><h3>Card Carrier</h3> </div><div class="content_prices clearfix"><div class="row_1"><p class="our_price_display" id="gift_value"><label>From Name <span class="small">(Up to 26 Characters)</span> </label></p><!-- quantity update/wanted --><p id="quantity_wanted_p"><span><input type="text" name="Fromname" id="Fromname_9_1" class="inputbox text" value="" size="25" maxlength="26" placeholder="From Name"> </span></p></div><div class="row_1"><p id="quantity_wanted_p"><select id="selectCarrierMessage_9_1" class="selectProductSort" name="selectCarrierMessage" style="width:170px;"><option value="">Add a  Message</option><option value="I appreciate you">I appreciate you</option><option value="Happy Birthday">Happy Birthday</option></select></p></div></div></span><div id="card_holder"><input type="checkbox" id="apply_all" name="apply_all" class="inputbox checkbox" checked="checked"><label>Apply these customization to all items</label></div><div id="delete_item"><a href="#" class="delete_item" id="delete_item"> <i class="icon-minus"></i> Remove </a> </div></div><!--Module Product Comments--></div><div id="pb-right-column" class="span4"><!-- product img-->    <div id="image-block"><span id="view_full_size"><div id="wrap" style="top:0px;z-index:auto;position:relative;"><img id="bigpic" alt="Vanilla VISA" title="Vanilla VISA" src="./static/images/products/mcgift/vanillaMC_1.png" rel="./static/images/products/mcgift/vanillaMC_1.png" style="display: block;"><span class="mask"><!--Hidden Data for securepay method blocks--><input type="hidden" id="product_item_9_1" name="product_item_9_1" value="product_item_9_1"><input type="hidden" id="productName" name="productName" value="Vanilla MC B2C Birthday" class="hide"><input type="hidden" id="productImage" name="productImage" value="./static/images/products/mcgift/vanillaMC_1.png" class="hide"><input type="hidden" id="productDesc" name="productDesc" value="Vanilla MC B2C Birthday Variable ($20 - $500) Open Value - $20-$500" class="hide"><input type="hidden" id="productShortDesc" name="productShortDesc" value="Vanilla MC B2C Birthday Variable ($20 - $500)" class="hide"><input type="hidden" id="productTextblock" name="productTextblock" value="" class="hide"><input type="hidden" id="giftPrice" name="giftPrice" value="NaN" class="hide"><input type="hidden" id="tax_9_1" name="tax_9_1" value="2.95" class="hide"><input type="hidden" id="toname_9_1" name="toname_9_1" value="undefined" class="hide" data-variable="toname_9_1"><input type="hidden" id="Fromname_9_1" name="Fromname_9_1" value="undefined" class="hide"><input type="hidden" id="selectPersonalMessage_9_1" name="selectPersonalMessage_9_1" value="undefined" class="hide"><input type="hidden" id="selectCarrierMessage_9_1" name="selectCarrierMessage_9_1" value="undefined" class="hide"><input type="hidden" id="productQty" name="productQty" value="" class="hide"><input type="hidden" id="uProductID" name="uProductID" value="9_1" class="hide"><input type="hidden" id="productID" name="productID" value="9" class="hide"> <input type="hidden" id="numProdID" name="numProdID" value="1" class="hide">  </span><div class="cn_preview">to name here</div><div class="tag_preview"> to message here</div><div class="abt_preview"></div></div></span></div></div> <!--MG took out 01-16-2014<div id="add_to_cart_individual" class="buttons_bottom_block"><a class="add_to_cart_button exclusive button btn_add_cart" href="#" id="btn_9_1" > <span>Add to cart </span></a><label for="addtocart"> shipping multiple-ship locations can be specific during checkout </label> </div>--></div><div id="product_item_9_2" class="thumbnails product_item_details"><!-- left infos--><div id="product_item_9_2" class="span4"><!-- add to cart form--><div id="tab-1"><h3 class="ProdNum">Card (2 of 3)</h3></div><!-- hidden datas --> <div class="product_attributes"><div class="content_prices clearfix"><!-- prices --><div class="row_1"><p class="our_price_display" id="gift_value"><label class="control-label" for="gift_9_1">Gift Value: ($20-$500)</label></p><!-- quantity update/wanted --><p id="quantity_wanted_p"><input type="text" name="giftprice" id="gift_9_1" class="input-medium" size="2" maxlength="3" value="20"></p></div><div class="row_1 fee"><p class="our_price_display" id="gift_value"><label class="control-label" for="tax_9_1">Card Fee: <a href="">?</a></label></p><!-- quantity update/wanted --><p id="quantity_wanted_p"><span><label for="fee">$</label><input id="tax_9_1" type="text" class="input-mini fee" readonly="" value="2.95"></span></p></div><div class="row_1"><div id="tab-1"><h3>Card <a href="">?</a></h3> </div><p class="our_price_display" id="gift_value"><label>To Name </label></p><!--quantity update/wanted --><p id="quantity_wanted_p"><span><label for="Toname"></label><input type="text" name="toname" id="toname_9_2" class="inputbox text" value="" size="25" maxlength="26" placeholder="Name"></span></p></div><div class="row_1"><!-- quantity update/wanted --><p id="quantity_wanted_p"><select id="selectPersonalMessage_9_2" class="selectProductSort" name="selectPersonalMessage" style="width:170px;"><option value="">Add a  Message</option><option value="I appreciate you">I appreciate you</option><option value="Happy Birthday">Happy Birthday</option></select></p></div> </div><!-- carrier message and information --><span class="Carrier"><div id="tab-2"><h3>Card Carrier</h3> </div><div class="content_prices clearfix"><div class="row_1"><p class="our_price_display" id="gift_value"><label>From Name <span class="small">(Up to 26 Characters)</span> </label></p><!-- quantity update/wanted --><p id="quantity_wanted_p"><span><input type="text" name="Fromname" id="Fromname_9_2" class="inputbox text" value="" size="25" maxlength="26" placeholder="From Name"> </span></p></div><div class="row_1"><p id="quantity_wanted_p"><select id="selectCarrierMessage_9_2" class="selectProductSort" name="selectCarrierMessage" style="width:170px;"><option value="">Add a  Message</option><option value="I appreciate you">I appreciate you</option><option value="Happy Birthday">Happy Birthday</option></select></p></div></div></span><div id="card_holder"><input type="checkbox" id="apply_all" name="apply_all" class="inputbox checkbox" checked="checked"><label>Apply these customization to all items</label></div><div id="delete_item"><a href="#" class="delete_item" id="delete_item"> <i class="icon-minus"></i> Remove </a> </div></div><!--Module Product Comments--></div><div id="pb-right-column" class="span4"><!-- product img-->   <div id="image-block"><span id="view_full_size"><div id="wrap" style="top:0px;z-index:auto;position:relative;"><img id="bigpic" alt="Vanilla VISA" title="Vanilla VISA" src="./static/images/products/mcgift/vanillaMC_1.png" rel="./static/images/products/mcgift/vanillaMC_1.png" style="display: block;"><span class="mask"><!--Hidden Data for securepay method blocks--><input type="hidden" id="product_item_9_2" name="product_item_9_2" value="product_item_9_2"><input type="hidden" id="productName" name="productName" value="Vanilla MC B2C Birthday" class="hide"><input type="hidden" id="productImage" name="productImage" value="./static/images/products/mcgift/vanillaMC_1.png" class="hide"><input type="hidden" id="productDesc" name="productDesc" value="Vanilla MC B2C Birthday Variable ($20 - $500) Open Value - $20-$500" class="hide"><input type="hidden" id="productShortDesc" name="productShortDesc" value="Vanilla MC B2C Birthday Variable ($20 - $500)" class="hide"><input type="hidden" id="productTextblock" name="productTextblock" value="" class="hide"><input type="hidden" id="giftPrice" name="giftPrice" value="NaN" class="hide"><input type="hidden" id="tax_9_2" name="tax_9_2" value="2.95" class="hide"><input type="hidden" id="toname_9_2" name="toname_9_2" value="undefined" class="hide" data-variable="toname_9_2"><input type="hidden" id="Fromname_9_2" name="Fromname_9_2" value="undefined" class="hide"><input type="hidden" id="selectPersonalMessage_9_2" name="selectPersonalMessage_9_2" value="undefined" class="hide"><input type="hidden" id="selectCarrierMessage_9_2" name="selectCarrierMessage_9_2" value="undefined" class="hide"><input type="hidden" id="productQty" name="productQty" value="" class="hide"><input type="hidden" id="uProductID" name="uProductID" value="9_2" class="hide"><input type="hidden" id="productID" name="productID" value="9" class="hide"> <input type="hidden" id="numProdID" name="numProdID" value="2" class="hide">  </span><div class="cn_preview">to name here</div><div class="tag_preview"> to message here</div><div class="abt_preview"></div></div></span></div></div> <!--MG took out 01-16-2014<div id="add_to_cart_individual" class="buttons_bottom_block"><a class="add_to_cart_button exclusive button btn_add_cart" href="#" id="btn_9_2" > <span>Add to cart </span></a><label for="addtocart"> shipping multiple-ship locations can be specific during checkout </label> </div>--></div><div id="product_item_9_3" class="thumbnails product_item_details"><!-- left infos--><div id="product_item_9_3" class="span4"><!-- add to cart form--><div id="tab-1"><h3 class="ProdNum">Card (3 of 3)</h3></div><!-- hidden datas --> <div class="product_attributes"><div class="content_prices clearfix"><!-- prices --><div class="row_1"><p class="our_price_display" id="gift_value"><label class="control-label" for="gift_9_1">Gift Value: ($20-$500)</label></p><!-- quantity update/wanted --><p id="quantity_wanted_p"><input type="text" name="giftprice" id="gift_9_1" class="input-medium" size="2" maxlength="3" value="20"></p></div><div class="row_1 fee"><p class="our_price_display" id="gift_value"><label class="control-label" for="tax_9_1">Card Fee: <a href="">?</a></label></p><!-- quantity update/wanted --><p id="quantity_wanted_p"><span><label for="fee">$</label><input id="tax_9_1" type="text" class="input-mini fee" readonly="" value="2.95"></span></p></div><div class="row_1"><div id="tab-1"><h3>Card <a href="">?</a></h3> </div><p class="our_price_display" id="gift_value"><label>To Name </label></p><!--quantity update/wanted --><p id="quantity_wanted_p"><span><label for="Toname"></label><input type="text" name="toname" id="toname_9_3" class="inputbox text" value="" size="25" maxlength="26" placeholder="Name"></span></p></div><div class="row_1"><!-- quantity update/wanted --><p id="quantity_wanted_p"><select id="selectPersonalMessage_9_3" class="selectProductSort" name="selectPersonalMessage" style="width:170px;"><option value="">Add a  Message</option><option value="I appreciate you">I appreciate you</option><option value="Happy Birthday">Happy Birthday</option></select></p></div> </div><!-- carrier message and information --><span class="Carrier"><div id="tab-2"><h3>Card Carrier</h3> </div><div class="content_prices clearfix"><div class="row_1"><p class="our_price_display" id="gift_value"><label>From Name <span class="small">(Up to 26 Characters)</span> </label></p><!-- quantity update/wanted --><p id="quantity_wanted_p"><span><input type="text" name="Fromname" id="Fromname_9_3" class="inputbox text" value="" size="25" maxlength="26" placeholder="From Name"> </span></p></div><div class="row_1"><p id="quantity_wanted_p"><select id="selectCarrierMessage_9_3" class="selectProductSort" name="selectCarrierMessage" style="width:170px;"><option value="">Add a  Message</option><option value="I appreciate you">I appreciate you</option><option value="Happy Birthday">Happy Birthday</option></select></p></div></div></span><div id="card_holder"><input type="checkbox" id="apply_all" name="apply_all" class="inputbox checkbox" checked="checked"><label>Apply these customization to all items</label></div><div id="delete_item"><a href="#" class="delete_item" id="delete_item"> <i class="icon-minus"></i> Remove </a> </div></div><!--Module Product Comments--></div><div id="pb-right-column" class="span4"><!-- product img-->   <div id="image-block"><span id="view_full_size"><div id="wrap" style="top:0px;z-index:auto;position:relative;"><img id="bigpic" alt="Vanilla VISA" title="Vanilla VISA" src="./static/images/products/mcgift/vanillaMC_1.png" rel="./static/images/products/mcgift/vanillaMC_1.png" style="display: block;"><span class="mask"><!--Hidden Data for securepay method blocks--><input type="hidden" id="product_item_9_3" name="product_item_9_3" value="product_item_9_3"><input type="hidden" id="productName" name="productName" value="Vanilla MC B2C Birthday" class="hide"><input type="hidden" id="productImage" name="productImage" value="./static/images/products/mcgift/vanillaMC_1.png" class="hide"><input type="hidden" id="productDesc" name="productDesc" value="Vanilla MC B2C Birthday Variable ($20 - $500) Open Value - $20-$500" class="hide"><input type="hidden" id="productShortDesc" name="productShortDesc" value="Vanilla MC B2C Birthday Variable ($20 - $500)" class="hide"><input type="hidden" id="productTextblock" name="productTextblock" value="" class="hide"><input type="hidden" id="giftPrice" name="giftPrice" value="NaN" class="hide"><input type="hidden" id="tax_9_3" name="tax_9_3" value="2.95" class="hide"><input type="hidden" id="toname_9_3" name="toname_9_3" value="undefined" class="hide" data-variable="toname_9_3"><input type="hidden" id="Fromname_9_3" name="Fromname_9_3" value="undefined" class="hide"><input type="hidden" id="selectPersonalMessage_9_3" name="selectPersonalMessage_9_3" value="undefined" class="hide"><input type="hidden" id="selectCarrierMessage_9_3" name="selectCarrierMessage_9_3" value="undefined" class="hide"><input type="hidden" id="productQty" name="productQty" value="" class="hide"><input type="hidden" id="uProductID" name="uProductID" value="9_3" class="hide"><input type="hidden" id="productID" name="productID" value="9" class="hide"> <input type="hidden" id="numProdID" name="numProdID" value="3" class="hide">  </span><div class="cn_preview">to name here</div><div class="tag_preview"> to message here</div><div class="abt_preview"></div></div></span></div></div> <!--MG took out 01-16-2014<div id="add_to_cart_individual" class="buttons_bottom_block"><a class="add_to_cart_button exclusive button btn_add_cart" href="#" id="btn_9_3" > <span>Add to cart </span></a><label for="addtocart"> shipping multiple-ship locations can be specific during checkout </label> </div>--></div></div>
```

See Entire Layout of three individual items to be added to cart. BUT the loop is not looping thru each item(div) on DOM page load..

Comment: That second piece of code just seems wrong... it uses `a` outside the loop it is defined in. How about putting the relevant parts in a JSFiddle (usually you will spot the problem yourself while doing that)?

Comment: it also looks like your selector `product_item_'+uProdID+'` is wrong. Is it meant to be `'product_item_'+uProdID`?

Comment: TrueBlueAussie, you are corrrect it should be product_item_'+uProdID+'..

Comment: What about the structure of the loop, what do we need to change for it to actually work?

Comment: Your HTML is not valid. HTML id's must be unique, but the product id's are repeated (e.g. `id="product_item_1_1"`, or `gift_value`. You cannot really expect anyone to fix your code when the page/HTML is invalid to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why U are looping product? You dont wanna add product on some click or smth event?

Try this loop, it will go thru every .products item on page:

```
var productsInCart = new Array(); //it should be array of products in cart ID's
// .products are product listed in page
$('.products').each(function(){
   var product = $(this);
   var id = $(this).attr('id').substring(4);
   if( productsInCart.indexOf(id) > 0 )
     //here product is in cart
   else
     //here products isnt in cart
   //do here what u want to do with single item (product)

});
```

**EDIT**

```
$('.product_item_details').each(function(){
   //here do what u wanna do
});
```

Comment: Can anyone take alook at my function script and tell me how to loop thur it, for every item listed on page iwth it unique ID (uProdId)????? PLEASEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE.

Comment: Show some html with these elements, then ill help.

Comment: unbreak, see the #-div that are generated from the preious action (customize()). This create # of select customize products. then the user has to ad the custom details. Click add to cart and it adds all the items to cart as individual item.

Comment: See the HTML output when products customization selected. We need to just loop thru the Add to Cart Function for each product/item on the page/DOM. See HTML. Each has a unique ID...........

Comment: So you need loop like in my answer EDIT

Comment: It only looping thru at the same product_item_id, not moving to the next item to be added to the cart. See HTML there are 3-items with unique id, yet it keep going to the first one 9_1. then fails, on the second loop.. Then adds that one product to the shopping cart.